# Turning a huge TextEdit file of JSON into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, textedit

I have an extremely large list of JSON files in the form of a TextEdit document, each of which has 6 key-value pairs.

I would like to turn each key-value pair into a column name for a Pandas Dataframe, and list the values under the column.

```
{'column1': "stuff stuff", 'column2': "details details, ....}
```

Is there a standard way to do this?

I think you could begin uploading the file into a dataframe with

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(file_name)
```

I think each column could be created by iterating through each JSON document using groupby.

EDIT: I think the correct approach is to parse each JSON object into a Dataframe, and then create a function to iterate through all JSONs and create one Dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [read_json](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.read_json.html) or [json_normalize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html). You would indeed most likely read each file and then use for instance [pd.concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to combine them as required.

Something along the below lines should work, depending on what your file looks like (here assuming that each `json` `dictionary` makes up a line in the file:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
f = open('workfile', 'r')
for line in f:
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_json(line, orient='columns')])
```

Comment: This is the correct approach. However, the dataframe is shaped (20000, 1). How do you iterate through each object? At that point, is it easier to parse each key or use `read_json`?

Comment: IIUC, you have 1 text file with json dictionaries, each of which as 6 key-value pairs? Same keys for each?

Comment: Yes, same keys for each. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Sounds like one would read each file using standard python methods line by line (see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), parse using `pd.read_json()` and `pd.concat` them on the go. I can mock up an example.

Comment: I'll look. Thanks, an example would be helpful